# Creating frosted glass three webgl

Tags: three.js

I'm having trouble to find how to create a material with the look of frosted glass. I haven't found anything on the web that looks what I want to do.

I've tried a lot of settings for the material.

[In this link you can see what I'm trying to get..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAWba.jpg) 
Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Regards
Rikard

Comment: Please add what you have tried.

Comment: My mistake. The reason I didn’t add what I’ve tested with is because I tested a lot of them. But I mostly tested with MeshPhongMaterial and normal different colors with different settings like transparent, opacity, blending and some more that I can’t remember now.

Answer (score 0):

One way I've encountered that worked well for me in the past performed a `Blit` on the portion of the `framebuffer` you want frosted with the blur algo or normal pattern of your choice. A stencil mask as part of the glass shader is used to determine which portion should be affected and which should not.

This article has a nice writeup on glass refraction which, when used with a blur will give a good effect.
https://beclamide.medium.com/advanced-realtime-glass-refraction-simulation-with-webgl-71bdce7ab825

I know It's not WebGL per se, but I've used the below Unity frosted glass shader before, to great effect. You may be able to extract the pertinent pieces from it and use that knowledge to assemble a WebGL version. https://github.com/andydbc/unity-frosted-glass

I'm about to undertake this myself, and will update this answer with actual code 'if' I succeed.